# Can I convert a production disk to Dynamic?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hard-drive

I have a server that is running out of disk space on a partition. I can't expand to the partition running out of space because the disk is not dynamic?

From computer manager can I convert the disk to dynamic so I can move partitions around with out messing up the OS and day to day operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're not going to be able to "move partitions around" by converting the disk to dynamic, but you will be able to extend the partition you want by doing so.

As to what is affected by the change to dynamic disks, these days, the answer is pretty much nothing.  You won't be able to boot an OS older than Windows 2000 from a Dynamic disk, older versions of ESX had performance problems with using dynamics, as did some older SANs, but I can't think of anything modern that actually cares if your disk type is Dynamic or Basic.

[MSDN has a small run down, and instructions regarding `Disk Management`, and the differences between Basic and Dynamic disks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163552.aspx), but really, Basic disks are just around for backwards compatibility, with very old systems, and it's unlikely that the difference will amount to anything for you.